# Login Facebook Sdk without Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I developed android app to share on Facebook. But when Login if Facebook App is installed then my app take credentials from Facebook app.

How I can Login to Facebook using Facebook SDK in My app not in Facebook app.

login facebook button:

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                SendFacebook.this.user = user;
                updateUI();
                // It's possible that we were waiting for this.user to be populated in order to post a
                // status update.
                handlePendingAction();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a facebook app as a facebook developer. The options will be available in the https://developers.facebook.com/.

Create the app there pertaining to your mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to depend on [graph apis](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

and get the access token to get user's Data

Answer (score 1):

You can use [socialauth](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/part-1-using-socialauth-to-integrate-facebook-api-in-android) library  for face book login.You can download lib project from [here](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)